# compute in prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate

I know in prolog we ask for is that true or false ,
can we also do compute for example average and how the predicate look like?

Comment: How predicates "look like"? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can compute the average of a list of numbers and the predicate would look like this:

```
average(List, Result) :- length(List, Len), sum(List, Sum), Result is Sum / Len.

sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], Sum) :- sum(T, Temp), Sum is Temp + H.
```

Then you get:

```
?- average([1, 2, 3], X).
X = 2.
```

Comment: it is sort of clear , if i want avg of 3 numbers for example is this right ~~> average(A,B,C):- Average is(A+B+C)/3   , it print true no result ><

Comment: The rule `average(A, B, C) :- Average is (A + B + C) / 3` has no meaning at all, because `Average` is unbound, so the rule will just bind value `(A + B + C) / 3` to the variable `Average` and then return true. Something like `average(A, B, C, Average) :- Average is (A + B + C) / 3` would be more meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

Prolog **does not** ask if something is true of false.  That is a common misconception.  Prolog tries to **unify** query goals with program predicates.  If it succeeds, it returns an assignment to the variables appearing in the query.  If it fails - Which is not supposed to be the common case - It returns "false".

As for averages, see 3electrologos' answer.